# How to make select field from select * Flink

Tags: select, filter, stream, apache-flink, sliding-window

I am trying to join 2 selects.

I have to make a query in code, looks like this query

```
select *
from  Data
where numPers > 10 && Object = P1
```

and this

```
select *
from  Data
where numPers < 20 && Object == P1
```

And i need to only timestamps from the data without repeats

The program code i use is shown below

```
object Prog {

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure()

    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val tableEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env)

    val csvTableSource = CsvTableSource
      .builder
      .path("src/main/resources/data.stream")
      .field("numPers", Types.INT)
      .field("Object", Types.STRING)
      .field("TIMESTAMP", Types.STRING)
      .fieldDelimiter(",")
      .ignoreFirstLine
      .ignoreParseErrors
      .commentPrefix("%")
      .build()

    tableEnv.registerTableSource("Data", csvTableSource)

    val table = tableEnv.scan("Data") //this works
      .filter("numPers > 10")
      .select("*")


    val ds = tableEnv.toAppendStream(table, classOf[Row])

    ds.print()
    env.execute()
  }
}
```

But how can I add the second query to the first?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Which table do you want to join with? There is only one table (`Data`) and therefore nothing to join.

Comment: I am sorry for inaccurate question

I need to make

select *
from  Data
where numPers > 10 && Object = P1

and 

select *
from  Data
where numPers < 20 && Object == P1

I need to show only distinct TIMESTAMP by joining these two queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you don't need a join but just a `BETWEEN` predicate:

```
val query = "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE numPers BETWEEN 10 AND 20 AND Object = P1"
val table = tableEnv.sqlQuery(query)
```

Comment: Yes, in this case it works. 
I have also another data in which it cannot be implemented and I wanted to use this approach to the query. There is a field with string values. And if want to select for example how to print all timestamps in which next conditions are satisfied
where field = value1 && Object = P1 INNER JOIN BY TIMESTAMP where field = value2 && Object = P1